# test to see if string contains 2 letters followed by 7 numbers

Tags: java, string

I need to error check String `licenseNumber` which is supposed to contain 2 letters followed by 7 digits within the String. I'm very new to Java and am in the early stages of classes so all help would be appreciated. I only need to return a true or false.

I'm not sure if there is a way to use loops to check the String or if there is a smarter way.

Comment: you need a regex match

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: yes its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct regex will be `^.*[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}.*$`

```
String pattern = "^.*[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}.*$";
System.out.println( "aa1234567".matches(pattern) ); // true
System.out.println( "aa123456".matches(pattern) ); // false
System.out.println( "aaa12345678".matches(pattern) ); // true
```

Comment: what does the `.*` do different?

Comment: @TommyBarrett it says `.` any character `*` any number of times. So you won't match on exactly two letters and exactly seven digits, but as you requested in the question, you'll match when the string will contain two letters followed by seven digits somewhere in it

Comment: but what if I need it to only match exactly 2 letters and exactly 7 digits? the only way it can be is AA1234567. If the string is AAA1234567FR I need it to be false.

Comment: Then the other answer solves your problem, but my answer answers the question that you have asked

Comment: the question on my assignment is:
Error checking methods for the Realtor class: 
Check the license contains 2 letters followed by 7 digits within the String. It doesn't say exact so your answer would be correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions:

```
String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}$";
System.out.println( "aa1234567".matches(pattern) ); // true
System.out.println( "aa123456".matches(pattern) ); // false

boolean verifyLicense = licenseNumber.matches(pattern);
...
```

Comment: So if I add another String called pattern using the same as you posted..can I use `if (licenseNumber.matches(pattern)); 
             verifyLicense = true;`

Comment: Yes, just use my posted (edited it a second ago) pattern. Then you can call the `match` function of you strings and get a boolean from it. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Comment: The first line says exactly "There gonna be 2 alphabetical letters which might be in capital, then 7 number."
So if you apply .matches(pattern) on a string, it will return true only if this statement is true.
You can do `verifyLicense = licenseNumber.matches(pattern);`

Comment: ahh that's what I wasn't sure about. I didn't know how to compare a string without knowing what was exactly supposed to be inside. thank you so much!

Comment: will it return false if the String does not contain 2 letters then 7 numbers?

Comment: Yes it will. You can try it yourself, parsing it strings and printing the result to see how it works. You can even change the pattern and experience things ! Actually, reading the Oracle doc given by guenhter would be the best thing to do to understand how it works :)

Comment: It's a bad regex. `abc12345678` also contains two letters followed by seven digits.

Comment: But I hope you to get the idea. Feel free to vary with the `a-zA-Z0-9` as you need it.

Comment: @xenteros is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @TommyBarrett I added my solution below

Comment: @TommyBarrett why did you switch to this answer again?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very straight-forward and rather simple way. This would work for your specific issue (but for any license number that follows the description in your answer)

Well, say you have a string

```
String str = "ab1234567";
```

then you can get a `char` array:

```
char[] characters = str.toCharacterArray();
```

and then check if it is the right length:

```
boolean isValid = true;
if(characters.length==9){
    if((96<characters[0]<123 && 96<characters[1]<123) || (64<characters[0]<91&& 64<characters[1]<91)){//this checks if the first two characters are lowercase letters
        for(int i = 2; i< characters.length; i++){
            if(!(47<characters[i]<58)){//this checks if the rest are numbers.
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
     }else{
         isValid = false;
     }
 }else{
     isValid = false;
 }
```

and then if `isValid` is true in the end, then your string is a license plate.

Comment: Your algorithm fails for `aaa123456789`.

Comment: @xenteros well, that's not a valid number, because it has 9 digits and 3 letters. which is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: `contains 2 letters followed by 7 numbers` - this means that my example was correct.

Comment: wording in the OP could have been confusing. I'm still not exactly sure which one I truly need but this example would also work if I needed exactly 2 char followed by 7 numbers equaling a total of 9 chars and letters. With everything under or over 9 total would return false anyways.